# Find $a$ in this $2\sin^3x + a\sin 2x + \frac 92 \cos 2x - 9\cos x - 2ax + 6 $

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

> I was given $$2\sin^3x + a\sin 2x + \frac 92 \cos 2x  - 9\cos x - 2ax + 6$$ its extremum at $x=\frac {\pi}{3}; 0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$
>
> I was asked, Find $a$ and first derivative.

1st derivative  :
$$6\sin^2x\cos x + 2a\cos 2x - 9\sin 2x + 9\sin x - 2a$$

What should i do now?

Comment: Ummm.... $3 a + 17 + \tan a$.  Find $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should evaluate at $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Since it is given that the point is an extremum, the whole expression of the first derivative evaluates to 0.